# read text file from php with post

Tags: php, file, post, text, flat-file

What is the problem with my code? I've fot two files in the same folder: index.php and pass.txt:

This is pass.txt:

```
qwerty
```

And this is index.php:

```
<?php 

$password=file_get_contents('pass.txt');

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 < time()) {
        session_destroy(); } }
else {
    $_SESSION['pass']="" ;  $_SESSION['timeout']=time(); }


if (isset($_POST["pass"])) {
    $_SESSION['pass']=$_POST['pass'] ; 
}

if($_SESSION['pass'] == $password)  {
    echo 'you are logged in';
} else {
    echo'<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        </form>';
}

?>
```

PROBLEM: When I write 'qwerty' in the input field and submit, it doesn't display "your ale logged in"

It is a mere syntax question for further development, not intended to protect anything.

Other answered questions did not solve my problem.

Comment: What is the problem? You don't state this in your question.

Comment: Thought it was understood, modified, sorry, XXX

Comment: do you get `qwerty` in `echo($_SESSION['pass']);` ?

Comment: you have got `session_start()` at the very top of the page have you?

Comment: yes, I added the full code to question

Comment: what if you change `if($_SESSION['pass'] == $password)  {` to `if($_POST['pass'] == $password)  {`, do the get what you want ?, if yes, seems to be a session problem.

Comment: clever question but doesnt work

Comment: well then, your input is not posted, where's the submit button ?

Comment: it does the same function with enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may have been the call to `file_get_contents` - I tried the following and it appears to function correctly. ( oops, forgot the `session_start()` for this example )

```
<?php
        session_start();

        if( isset( $_SESSION['timeout'] ) && $_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 < time() ) session_destroy();
        else {
            $_SESSION['pass']="" ;
            $_SESSION['timeout']=time();
        }

        $password=file_get_contents( realpath( __DIR__.'/pass.txt' ), FILE_TEXT | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
        echo 'The password from the text file: '. $password;


        if( isset( $_POST["pass"] ) ) $_SESSION['pass']=$_POST['pass'] ; 

        if( strlen( $password ) > 0 && trim( $_SESSION['pass'] ) === trim( $password ) )  {
            echo 'you are logged in';
        } else {
            /* for dev I use a local file, aliased as /stackoverflow/ */
            echo'<form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="password" name="pass">
                    <input type="submit" value="login">
                </form>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: bingo, though quite complex for me

Comment: It is essentially the same code as yours - except for the `file_get_contents`. Which bits in particular do you find "complex"?

Answer (score 1):

In the begening of your index.php start session `session_start();`
To compare strings in php use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php `strcmp();`

```
if (strcmp($_SESSION['pass'], $password))  {
    echo 'you are logged in';
} else {
    echo'<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    </form>';
}
```

Comment: already added to the question, It seems not to be the problem... must have to do with file reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code-

```
<?php 

$password=file_get_contents(realpath( __DIR__.'/pass.txt' ),FILE_TEXT | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

if (isset($_POST["pass"])) {
    $_SESSION['pass']=$_POST['pass'] ; 
}

if($_SESSION['pass'] == $password)  {
    echo 'you are logged in';
} else {
    echo'<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        </form>';
}

?>
```

Comment: It didn't worked because of the method you replaced  `$password=file_get_contents('pass.txt',true);` when the answer was accepted from @RamRaider with  `$password=file_get_contents(realpath( __DIR__.'/pass.txt' ),FILE_TEXT | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`.